# Overcoming Sonar issue replace Map.get() and condition with a call to Map.computeIfAbsent()

Tags: java, hashmap, sonarqube

I have a below method. The implementation is if the map does not have `id` key, then the method inserts `id` and `name`.

But Sonar reports this line of code as a *Major* error and suggests to replace `Map.get()` and condition with a call to `Map.computeIfAbsent()`.

How to insert values into map using `computeIfAbsent`?

### Original Code

Here Sonar complains:

```
public void testMethod(List<Map<String, Object>> restultMapList) {
    for(Map<String, Object> resultMap : restultMapList) {
        if(resultMap.get("id")==null) {
            resultMap.put("id", "");
            resultMap.put("name", "");
        }
    }
}
```

### Attempt to use `computeIfAbsent`

I have tried the below but it throws error. Not sure  how to fix this.

```
public void testMethod(List<Map<String, Object>> restultMapList) {
    for(Map<String, Object> resultMap : restultMapList) {
        resultMap.computeIfAbsent("id", x-> x.put("id",""));
    }
}
```

Then following errors are shown:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
    - The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type String
```

Comment: x is not the map. x is the key, i.e. "id". computeIfAbsent is meant to replace a call to `if (myMap.get(myKey) == null) myMap.put(myKey, myValue);` with `myMap.computeIfAbsent(myKey, key -> myValue);`. Compute if absent avoids to search two times for the key, and ensure atomicity of the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the String value from the lambda function without any operations.

Alternatively, using `putIfAbsent` would make more sense as there in no computation involved. computeIfAbsent makes more sense where getting the value would involve some operation (e.g. in cache, if not present fetch from original source).

```
resultMap.putIfAbsent("id", "");
```

As for computeIfAbsent,

For reference, Method's Javadoc says

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
> mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping
> function and enters it into this map unless null.

Thus in your case, there is no computation as such - so you can return the string itself. The definition of the function is:

> Params: key – key with which the specified value is to be associated
>
> mappingFunction – the function to compute a value
>
> Returns: the current
> (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or
> null if the computed value is null

The following snippet will work for you:

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
resultMap.computeIfAbsent("id", s -> "FirstValue");
System.out.println(resultMap.get("id"));             // FirstValue
resultMap.computeIfAbsent("id", s -> "NewValue");
System.out.println(resultMap.get("id")); 
// Still FirstValue as id was already present
```

Here the Lamda `s -> "NewValue"` can be expanded to `(String s) -> "NewValue"`

For the second part - the error "Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above" indicates wrong environment in IDE probably, where you would need to set language API level to 1.8 or above, or check the library settings.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Rule

The Sonar rule for Java with [RSPEC-3824](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3824) applies for Java 8 only:

> **"Map.get" and value test should be replaced with single method call**
>
> It’s a common pattern to test the result of a `java.util.Map.get()` against `null` or calling `java.util.Map.containsKey()` before proceeding with adding or changing the value in the map. However the `java.util.Map` API offers a significantly better alternative in the form of the `computeIfPresent()` and `computeIfAbsent()` methods. Using these instead leads to cleaner and more readable code.
>
> **Note** that this rule is automatically disabled when the project’s sonar.java.source is not 8.

Let's assume your project is configured for the use of Java 8.

#### The Sonar compliant solution

From:

```java
if (resultMap.get("id") == null) {
    resultMap.put("id", "");
    resultMap.put("name", "");
}
```

To use with [`putIfAbsent(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-):

```java
resultMap.putIfAbsent("id", "");  // empty string as default
```

Note:

- this solution does not compute anything, no lambda needed.
- here `resultMap.put("name", "");` is not called if key `"id"` was not present.

Both methods `putIfAbsent` and [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) were added to interface `Map` with Java version 8.

See also:

- Tutorial on Baeldung: [A Guide to Java HashMap, 4.3. putIfAbsent()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap#3-putifabsent)
- Tutorial on Baeldung: [The Map.computeIfAbsent() Method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-computeifabsent)